# Seeking QGIS equivalent for ArcGIS route editing tools?

Tags: qgis, editing, route

In ArcGIS Desktop I frequently use the route editing Tools for line features and I was wondering if the same or similar tools exist in QGIS as well. I couldn't find them so far.

With "create route" I can select two or more line objects from my line feature layer and the tool creates a new object combining the selected lines and giving me the length of the route from the start of the first line till the end of the last line.

Does anyone know whether these tools exist in QGIS or not?

Comment: Could you explain what the route editing tools does in ArcGis ? what specific functionality did you want to use ?

Comment: With "create route" I can select two or more line objects from my line feature layer and the tool creates a new object combining the selected lines and giving me the length of the route from the start of the first line till the end of the last line.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the closest would be the [LRS pluggin](http://blazek.github.io/lrs/)

> **Features**
>
> - Standard LRS tasks: calibration (creation of LRS), creation of    punctual and linear events and calculation of measures for points.
> - Support for all vector formats supported by QGIS.
> - Supported are lines, multi-lines, points, multi-points. The lines    don’t need to be oriented. Single route may be represented by
>     multiple features.
> - Dynamic list and layer of errors and layer of quality which are    updated immediately when source layer features is edited.
> - The generated LRS is stored in memory only.
> - Interpolation between points by default, optional extrapolation.